# SQL / HiveQL to assign values to buckets based on a table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table "bucket" containing minimum int values for buckets, like this

```
min_value bucket_id
--------- ---------
       0      1
   12345      2
   67890      3
```

i.e. any value >= 0 and < 12345 belongs in bucket 1, ..., any value >= 67890 belongs in bucket 3.

and a table of int values "value" like this:

```
id value
-- -----
11    10
22 20000
33 80000
```

I would like to figure out which bucket each value belongs to. So

```
select id, bucket_id
from (some join, or whatever, of bucket and value)
```

gives me

```
id bucket_id
-- ---------
11     1
22     2
33     3
```

I am trying to implement this in HiveQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that the condition for the bucket with largest `min_value` is `min_value <= value` (since there is no bucket with larger `min_value`) and I also assumed integer type for column `value` of table `value` and column `min_value` of table `bucket` (that's important because the query uses comparison which works differently in case of string type so you need to do typecasting for string).

The following query works for non-negative `value` of table `value`, in case of negative values involved, you have to replace
`max(if(a.value >= b.min_value, b.min_value, 0))`
with
`max(if(a.value >= b.min_value, b.min_value, <minimum possible value that "value" field may have>))`:

```
select 
c.id, 
if(d.bucket_id is null, 'not in bucket', d.bucket_id)

from
(    
  select     
  a.id,
  max(if(a.value >= b.min_value, b.min_value, 0)) as bucket_min_value    
  from    
  value a    
  left join     
  bucket b    
  group by a.id    
)    
c

left join    
bucket d    
on c.bucket_min_value = d.min_value    
;
```

Comment: Yes, ints. I've added that to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to define ranges for the bucket ids and then join the bucket table. Check this out.

```
> select * from bucket;
+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| bucket.min_value  | bucket.bucket_id  |
+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 0                 | 1                 |
| 12345             | 2                 |
| 67890             | 3                 |
+-------------------+-------------------+--+

> select * from buckvalue;
+---------------+------------------+--+
| buckvalue.id  | buckvalue.value  |
+---------------+------------------+--+
| 11            | 10               |
| 22            | 20000            |
| 33            | 80000            |
+---------------+------------------+--+

> select bucket_id, min_value, lead(min_value) over(order by bucket_id)  as max1 from bucket;
INFO  : OK
+------------+------------+--------+--+
| bucket_id  | min_value  |  max1  |
+------------+------------+--------+--+
| 1          | 0          | 12345  |
| 2          | 12345      | 67890  |
| 3          | 67890      | NULL   |
+------------+------------+--------+--+

> select t1.id, t1.value, t2.bucket_id from buckvalue t1 left outer join ( select bucket_id, min_value, lead(min_value) over(order by bucket_id)  as max1 from bucket ) t2
where t1.value >= t2.min_value and t1.value < coalesce(t2.max1,99999);

+--------+-----------+---------------+--+
| t1.id  | t1.value  | t2.bucket_id  |
+--------+-----------+---------------+--+
| 11     | 10        | 1             |
| 22     | 20000     | 2             |
| 33     | 80000     | 3             |
+--------+-----------+---------------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple query to do this. It works by finding all the bucket numbers for which the value is greater than the bucket's minimum value, and taking the maximum bucket_id.

```
create temporary table bucket as select * from (select 0 min_value, 1 bucket_id union select 12345, 2 union select 67890, 3) a;
create temporary table value as select * from (select 11 id, 10 value union select 22, 20000 union select 33, 80000) a;

select value.id, max(bucket.bucket_id) bucket_id
from value
join bucket
where value.value > bucket.min_value
group by value.id;
```

Comment: what is the hive version that is used?

Comment: Hive 1.2, MapR distribution:  
    Hive 1.2.0-mapr-json-1710  
    Subversion git://35e44e05a8a9/root/opensource/mapr-hive-1.2/dl/mapr-hive-1.2 -r ff9272d8f9dd859ac982bb32d0e3dc5acd7ead4f  
    Compiled by root on Mon Oct 30 18:19:56 UTC 2017  
    From source with checksum 07ae5487de4e08bffbf15ebbd119411a

Comment: well, for your case it works because the larger bucket minvalue implies the larger bucket ID, otherwise the query is wrong. consider buckets {"minvalue:0, id:1", "minvalue:67890, id:2", "minvalue:12345, id:3"} or {"minvalue:67890, id:1", "minvalue:12345, id:2", "minvalue:0, id:3"}  or {"minvalue:12345, id:1", "minvalue:0, id:2", "minvalue:67890, id:3"}

Comment: even for your case it is wrong since you use ">" instead of ">=" in "where value.value > bucket.min_value", so the elements equal to bucket minvalues will be assigned to wrong buckets. the correct version is in both the answers given. I would give a credit to the answer of user "stack0114106" since he used a compact way of "lead() over()" to avoid double join and double select